# How to spot where is variable come from?

Tags: yii2

I am building in local then upload in production, but in production I have some variable appear, but I don't know where is come from.

Here is the picture

[image]

so "0" will appear if cart is not empty, if cart contain 2 items the "0" will be two.

I thought it come from session but when I check session from yii2 debug there is no session which value is "0";

"0" appear excactly before `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
0</br>0</br>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="private,max-age:3600">
```

it's my view named `utama.php` here is partial code `utama.php`

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Url;
use backend\modules\company\assets\HomeAsset;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\assets\FoAsset;
use yii\helpers\VarDumper;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\base\View;
use common\models\TbCustomer;
use yii\web\JsExpression;
use common\models\TbKategori;
use common\component\BeoHelper;
use common\models\TbSubKategori1;
use common\models\TbSubKategori2;
use common\models\TbMenuPromo;
use yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice;
use kartik\typeahead\Typeahead;
use common\models\EAktorType;
use common\models\VwProdukAgent;


$aset  =  FoAsset::register($this);
?>

//how come "0" can be here?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="private,max-age:3600">
so on....
```

In case I don't know where is come from or I just forget where is the echo.

Can I spot where is come from and remove it?

If you need more information, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it appear before `<!DOCTYPE html>` so it come from `CartController` action `index` there will be `echo` just find it.